# MSSQL WHERE with IF

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, where-clause

I am trying to get a query that does the below:

```
SELECT * FROM Test
WHERE
IF Condition = True
    Column1 = 'This'
    Column2 = 'That'
ELSE
    Column3 = 'This'
    column4 = 'That'
```

The only thing I can find with If Conditions in a where clause are CASES. I have not been able to find an example that allows cases for multiple conditions.

So far I have had to achieve this by having the If outside of the SELECT statement and duplicating the statement but changing the WHERE clause.

Comment: Please clarify if the `=` operator is assignment or an equality-test, and please provide an example `Condition`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Test
WHERE
(Condition = True
    AND Column1 = 'This'
    AND Column2 = 'That')
OR
(Condition = FALSE
    AND Column3 = 'This'
    AND column4 = 'That')
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems very obvious when put in front of you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PROCEDURE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) or [FUNCTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) to do this.

For example with PROCEDURE:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test (IN _condition BOOLEAN, IN _this VARCHAR(255), IN _that VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    IF _condition THEN
        SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Column1 = _this AND Column2 = _that;
    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Column3 = _this AND Column4 = _that;
    END IF;
END;
```

To run this, just execute `CALL test(TRUE, 'This', 'That')`

You can replace **_condition** with your own condition, for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test1 (IN _number INT(11), IN _this VARCHAR(255), IN _that VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    IF _number >= 2016 THEN
        SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Column1 = _this AND Column2 = _that;
    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Column3 = _this AND Column4 = _that;
    END IF;
END;
```

And execute `CALL test1(2015, 'This', 'That')`